# All plugins stop working on iframe page load - Cordova (phonegap) 3.3, JQM 1.3.2, IOS

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the following scenario: I wrote an app that works on Android. now I'm trying to "port" it to ios.

Everything is working fine except for a very simple page where I load a url inside an iframe.

When going to this page all the plugins stop working.

1. it happens only in ios - Android works great.
2. sometime it only happen on the 2 time when I go to the page with the iframe.
3. I'm using Cordova 3.3, JQM 1.3.2, Xcode5 (ios7), jquery 1.8.2 (happens also with jq 1.9)
4. I tried different techniques of entering the url in the iframe - mostly got same or worse results.
5. The log display 'Resetting plugins due to page load' - I read all the stackoverflow question about 'Resetting plugins due to page load' - non of them were relevant.
   BTW - 'Resetting plugins due to page load.' displayed at the log (5th line) every time the app start with no relation to this issue.
6. One solution I found is to revert back to phonegap 2.9, there the camera/video are in the core so they doesn't stop working after the iframe is loaded, the reason I'm using v3.3 is because of some plugins, I will try to install these plugin in v2.9 but my guess is that they will fail after the iframe displays.
7. Another solution is to use InAppBrowser plugin which opens the url in a full page, but then I couldn't embed the frame (e.g. youtube) inside a page in my app

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5712 and follow it:

1. `git clone git://git.apache.org/cordova-ios.git` 
   (3.5.0-dev)
2. override the CordovaLib in your project with the new one.

Although this solve the issue, I just found that after opening a camera, the softkeyboard become a total mess... I must say THERE ARE TOO MANY BUG IN CORDOVA IOS.